# changing the layout from a select form bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

Attached you can see a picture, which is a form that clients should use to contact me. As you can see, the select form is not in the same layout than the others. I want to add an icon as well, but it looks stupid because it is a rect closed to round corners. I have found many ways to change that, but with huge libraries, which I don't need (e.g. http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/ or http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20731482/contact.png

How can I change the layout and include the icon on the left side easily?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a regular `select` ?

```
<div class="input-prepend">
  <span class="add-on">@</span>
  <select id="inputSelection">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
</div>
```

You can see how it [works](http://bootply.com/76493).

Comment: because the corners from right side of the add-on are not exactly connected to the left once in the selection box... I want to change the layout so that it looks 100% professional

Comment: Did you check my sample?

Comment: Yes I did, but on Mac it is no correct, have a look:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20731482/contact2.png

(I know that the add-on is way to big, but that doesn't matter because its about the corners ;-) )

Comment: Grab your form and create a fiddle so we can help.

Comment: If you are not working on a mac this wont help. I just copy pasted your code. Have a look at the fiddle you've done for me, on mac it's just not correct:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20731482/fiddle.png

Comment: You're right but it seems more like a problem with safari. I've tested it with safari on Win 7 and other platforms and it does not render properly.